# AngularJS md-select limit options

Tags: angularjs, material-design

Is there a way to limit the displayed option in the md-select tag because it is defaulted to 5 options. Thanks in advance

edit:

```
<md-select ng-model="aaa" name="bbb" required>
                        <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                        <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                        <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
                        <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
                        <md-option value="5">5</md-option>
                        <md-option value="6">6</md-option>
                        <md-option value="7">7</md-option>
                        <md-option value="8">8</md-option>
                        <md-option value="9">9</md-option>
                        <md-option value="10">10</md-option>
                        <md-option value="11">11</md-option>
                        <md-option value="12">12</md-option>
                        <md-option value="13">13</md-option>
                        <md-option value="14">14</md-option>
                    </md-select-menu>
                </md-select>
```

Comment: Paste your template here.

Comment: I want it to display more than 5 options

Comment: I've used `md-select-menu md-content { overflow-y: auto !important; }` to show scrollbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for `md-select-menu` and `md-select-menu md-content` in the AngularJS's Material Design CSS file and change the `max-height` value - default to 256px.

Would be better to add your own class to those elements (or just use a parent class) and override the value.

**EDIT**
Demo url: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MabBxg
This is the demo from material design website where I added more options and the following css lines:

```
body md-select-menu, body md-content{
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

**Note:** because this is `max-height`, the number of options displayed in your application also depends on your window height. Even in the demo page, you'll have to lower the height of the top frame in order to see more options.

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: will it work also if the css is inline with the md-select tag?

Comment: ``body`` shouldn't be affected by that css rule. If you inspect the body element on demo page you'll see that there's no ``max-height`` property attached to it. It should work with inline css, why not. I think you can use the ``ng-style`` directive to keep everything "the angular way"

Comment: how? I'm new in angular js have no idea how

Comment: for ``ngStyle`` directive you have everything you need here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle & for AngularJS In general you should read Developer Guide/Tutorial/API Reference from their website.